# React Router 5 - handle POP as hard reload for route?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Lets say I have the routes:

```
/fruit-inventory
/apples
/bananas
/pears
```

The user arrives on `/fruit-inventory` and may navigate via react router to the fruit pages. Eg:
`/fruit-inventory -> /apples -> /bananas -> /pears <back> -> /bananas`. If hitting `back` again would take them to `/fruit-inventory`, then I want the whole page to be refreshed as if they had hit the browser refresh button.

I've tried adding the component below:

```
const RequireReload: React.FC = ({}) => {
    const history = useHistory()
    useEffect(() => {
        history.location.state = { reload: true }
        history.replace(history.location)
        history.listen((location, action) => {
            if (action == "POP" && location.state !== undefined && location.state.reload) {
                window.location.href = location.pathname
            }
        })
    })
}
```

This sort of works, but it doesn't prevent React Router from rendering the `/fruit-inventory` route while the request to the server is in progress. I'd like it to instead stay on the `/apples` page until the browser finishes reloading `/fruit-inventory` from the server.

Comment: you can put forRefresh on Router like: `<BrowserRouter forceRefresh={true}>`

Comment: @webcoder that would apply on the all the routes then

Answer (score 1):

I was able to accomplish my goal with this, which works for History V4 (used by React Router 5):

```
const CheckPopForReload: React.FC = ({}) => {
    const history = useHistory()
    useEffect(() => {
        const unblock = history.block((location, action) => {
            // @ts-ignore
            if (action == "POP" && location.state !== undefined && location.state.reload) {
                window.location.href = location.pathname
                return false
            }
        })
        return unblock
    })
    return null
}
const RequireReload: React.FC = ({}) => {
    const history = useHistory()
    useEffect(() => {
        history.location.state = { reload: true }
        history.replace(history.location)
    })
    return null
}
```

```
class Root {
    render() {
        const checkPop = <CheckPopForReload/>
        return <Provider store={this.props.store}>
            <Router history={history}>
                {checkPop}
                <Route path={"/fruit-inventory"}>
                    <RequireReload/>
                </Route>
            </Router>
        </Provider>
    }
}
```

The docs for this function are here: https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/v4/docs/Blocking.md. It's not clear from that page alone, but returning false blocks the route and not returning anything permits it. That can be seen in the definition here:
https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/v4/modules/createTransitionManager.js#L16